# Getting 404 error from my Visual Studio Web api

Tags: visual-studio, webapi

I have a controller that has 2 get methods: one gets all and one gets a single result.

The single result one gets a 404 error (not there), but it is there. What am I missing?  All the other methods work (add, update, delete).

This one works:
https://localhost:44334/api/user/GetUsers

This one does not work. It doesn't even get to the break point. Gives me a status "404 not found".

https://localhost:44334/api/user/GetUser/12

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you dont need fromroute create signature like this

```
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("GetUser/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

ignore [Authorize] if not using any, probaly better renaming though to something better like 'GetUserbyID'